# How to send order number and order amount to GTM on successful palce order using data layer in magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, google-tag-manager, magento2.4

I want to send the order number and order amount to GTM using data layer in magento 2. so i called the js file in checkout_index_index.xml and
this is my js code to send the data to GTM

```
require([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order'
], function(placeOrderAction) {
    'use strict';

    placeOrderAction().done(function(orderData) {
        var orderId = orderData['order_id'];
        var orderAmount = orderData['base_grand_total'];

        console.log('Order placed successfully. Order ID: ' + orderId + ', Order Amount: ' + orderAmount);

        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'OrderPlaced',
            'orderNumber': orderId,
            'orderAmount': orderAmount
        });
    })
});
```

But its not working. How can i achieve this.

Thanks!